# IF statements in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an `if` statement which is giving the the error message 
`End if without block if`

Ive tried placing the `End if` just before the `sub` and just after the `if` statement.

I also tried placing 2 `end if` statements at the end of each `IF` statement.

```
If IDtype = "UK" Then sqluserfix = " & UserId & "

If IDtype = "NE" Then sqluserfix = "(select USER_ID from USER_PARAMS where USER_ID2='" & UserId & "')"

End If
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your case you are using what is called a *one line statement*

```
If (true) then MsgBox "No End If required!"
```

This works and doesn't require an `End If` statement because it's a *one-liner*.

Because you **do** have an `End If` statement that's why the error occurs, because you trying to end an `If` statement which has not been started ( *2 one-liners* ).

In C# you for example a `;` semi-colon acts as a line separator. In VB/VBA you use the <kbd>Return</kbd> key to separate lines.

---

You can do exactly the same thing two other ways

1)

```
If (true) then _ 
    MsgBox "No End If required!"
```

2)

```
If (true) then
    MsgBox "End If required!!!"
End If
```

---

However in your case it seems that a more suitable *decision* would be to use a combination of `If` and `ElseIf` like this

```
If IDtype = "UK" Then
    sqluserfix = " & UserId & "
ElseIf IDtype = "NE" Then
    sqluserfix = "(select USER_ID from USER_PARAMS where USER_ID2='" & UserId & "')"
End If
```

Comment: + 1 If I was a layman, this would really make things clear for me :) Also this addresses the reason for the error.

Answer (score 7):

VBA `If` statements can be done inline like so:

```
If IDtype = "UK" Then sqluserfix = " & UserId & "
```

Or be done on multiple lines like so:

```
If IDtype = "NE" Then
    sqluserfix = "(select USER_ID from USER_PARAMS where USER_ID2='" & UserId & "')"    
End If
```

Your problem is that you are mixing both at the same time, choose one format and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: + 1 If I was a layman, this would really make things clear for me :) Also this addresses the reason for the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `End If` if you use multi-line formatting:

```
If something Then
    'do something
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Are there only 2 options? Just surprised no one has suggested `Select Case`

```
Select Case IDtype
    Case "UK"
        sqluserfix = " & UserId & "
    Case "NE"
        sqluserfix = "(select USER_ID from USER_PARAMS where USER_ID2='" & UserId & "')"
End Select
```

Comment: -1 While I appreciate your effort to share knowledge this answer in the current form does not seem to address the question (like Q:"why does my car not start?", A: "you could take the bus"). Posting this as a comment on the question or comment on the accepted answer seems more appropriate. If you find the formatting options too limited you could share the knowledge as a new (self-answered) question (e.g. "what are the options for conditional code execution in VBA?") and add a comment here to link to it. Or link to an existing answer like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455552/2799887

Answer (score 1):

In this case use `ElseIf`:

```
If IDtype = "UK" Then 
  sqluserfix = " & UserId & "
ElseIf IDtype = "NE" Then 
  sqluserfix = "(select USER_ID from USER_PARAMS where USER_ID2='" & UserId & "')"
End If
```

---

By the Way this Statements can also look like this:

```
If IDtype = "UK" Then 
  sqluserfix = " & UserId & "
End If

If IDtype = "NE" Then 
  sqluserfix = "(select USER_ID from USER_PARAMS where USER_ID2='" & UserId & "')"
End If
```

---

[Formating Code in VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163834%28v=office.10%29.aspx) shows you how to do this in a right way.