# IF Without End IF in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement

see the code below.

```
IF Weight=0 Then CallFunction

IF Weight=100 Then
Heavy=True
Else 
Heavy= False
End If
```

How is the program working when I have not ended a **if statement**?

Comment: Have you tried to execute it?

Comment: @MaciejLos yes I have executed it and it works.

Comment: And what's your issue? If `Weight` is equal to zero, then `CallFunction` is executed, then code is going to `if` statement. That's all! Debug the program to find out ;)

Comment: I raised the question to just get expertise on how can the code run as I have been getting errors in other programs where I didn't write a End IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

its VBA's functionality to end up if statements in a single line..

Comment: It's a language feature of the Basic language that is decades old and is present in all versions of the language. The accepted answer in the linked question concerns the `IF` operator that is a completely different thing (a ternary operator, new to VB.NET). VBA does not have the `IF` ternary operator at all, only the `IF` clause and the `IIf` function.

Comment: @Vijay's answer _is_ correct, but as GSerg pointed out, the link isn't relevant.  Maybe Vijay can edit his answer.

Comment: Newbie on stackoverflow...
so needed to reply up fast to get some fair reputation....
didn't went through the answer thoroughly.
thanks @GuitarPicker

Comment: @GSerg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541024/if-statements-in-vba This is proper.

Comment: @Meesha Yes it is, which is why I have voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

If `Weight` is equal to zero, then `CallFunction` is executed (if `Weight` is not equal to zero, a `CallFunction` is not executed), then the code is going to another `if` statement. That's all! Debug the program to find out ;)

Comment: The OP was wondering why it was syntactically possible to have an `If` that does not have a corresponding `End If`.

Comment: Thank you all downvoters! No comments, no chance to improve my answer. Thank you again.

Comment: No, @GSerg, OP wants to explain what code do... See: "*How is the program working when I have not ended a if statement?*"

Comment: No, the OP is asking why the program is working even though they did not provide an `End If`, provided that previously, when they had forgotten to provide an `End If`, the program [would have not worked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856872/if-without-end-if-in-vba/29857124?noredirect=1#comment47840102_29856872), but this time it works for some reason. "How is this working" means "Why is it working" as well in English.

Comment: @GSerg, :laugh: `How` is not equal to `Why`! And it does not mean "Why is it working" as per my understanding. Does it is the reason of downovote? Please, read OP comments to the question.