VBA: "End If without block If" - Thought I ended all if statements
When I go through the code I have an "End If" that vba tells me does not have a corresponding "If" block with it.  If you cut and paste the code into Notepad++, the error happens on line 638. Below the code I will include a summarized version for ease of seeing the "conditional statements".  I know there are probably better and more efficient ways to do this, but I am looking for the issue with this particular code and would like to avoid having to do a full re-write if possible. Any help to figure out where the issue lies is greatly appreciated.
Here is the code:
Public Sub increments()

    'check 

    Dim main As Worksheet: Set main = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("main")
    Dim pc As Worksheet: Set pc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Programs_Courses")
    Dim pso As Worksheet: Set pso = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ps_output")
    lastrow = main.Range("A" & main.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim DestRow As Integer
    
    'programs variable declarations
    Dim acc_con As Integer, _
    bunch of others...

    Dim gen_manag_con As Integer, _
    bunch of others...
    
    
    'initialize program variables to 0
    acc_con = 0
    all other variables also set to 0
    DestRow = 2
    
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    
        If main.Cells(i, 1) = main.Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
            
            'Accounting 1
            If main.Cells(i, 7) = pc.Cells(3, 3) Then
                    
                acc_con = acc_con + 1
                more increments
                    
            'Accounting 2
            ElseIf main.Cells(i, 7) = pc.Cells(4, 3) Then
            
                ton more incrementing but had to cut due to length
            
            End If
                
                
            'Check for concentrator status
            If acc_con = 2 Or _
               pl_an_sys_con = 50 Or _
               auto_tech_con = 2 Or _
               cul_art_con = 2 Or _
               dig_art_des_con = 2 Or _
               ece_con = 2 Or _
               envi_nat_res_con = 2 Or _
               gen_manag_con = 2 Or _
               graph_comm_con = 2 Or _
               health_sci_con = 2 Or _
               horti_con = 1 Or _
               mark_manag_con = 2 Or _
               media_tech_con = 2 Or _
               pltw_biomed_sci_con = 2 Or _
               pltw_pre_eng_con = 2 Or _
               pltw_pre_eng_con = 3 Or _
               sports_med_con = 2 Or _
               fam_con_sci_con = 2 Or _
               prog_soft_dev_con = 2 Then

                    pc.Activate
                    term_match = Application.Match(main.Cells(i, 14), pc.Range(Cells(4, 77), Cells(30, 77)), 0)
                    
                    If IsError(term_match) Then
                    ElseIf term_match > 0 Then
                    
                        If IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 2)) Then
                            
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 2) = "Y"
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 6) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                        
                        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 2)) And IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 8)) Then
                            
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 8) = "Y"
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 12) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                        
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                    
                    
                    'reset concentrator
                    If acc_con = 2 Then acc_con = 0
                    ElseIf pl_an_sys_con = 50 Then pl_an_sys_con = 0
                    ElseIf auto_tech_con = 2 Then auto_tech_con = 0
                    ElseIf cul_art_con = 2 Then cul_art_con = 0
                    ElseIf dig_art_des_con = 2 Then dig_art_des_con = 0
                    ElseIf ece_con = 2 Then ece_con = 0
                    ElseIf envi_nat_res_con = 2 Then envi_nat_res_con = 0
                    ElseIf gen_manag_con = 2 Then gen_manag_con = 0
                    ElseIf graph_comm_con = 2 Then graph_comm_con = 0
                    ElseIf health_sci_con = 2 Then health_sci_con = 0
                    ElseIf horti_con = 1 Then horti_con = 0
                    ElseIf mark_manag_con = 2 Then mark_manag_con = 0
                    ElseIf media_tech_con = 2 Then media_tech_con = 0
                    ElseIf pltw_biomed_sci_con = 2 Then pltw_biomed_sci_con = 0
                    ElseIf pltw_pre_eng_con = 2 Then pltw_pre_eng_con = 0
                    ElseIf pltw_pre_eng_con = 3 Then pltw_pre_eng_con = 0
                    ElseIf sports_med_con = 2 Then sports_med_con = 0
                    ElseIf fam_con_sci_con = 2 Then fam_con_sci_con = 0
                    ElseIf prog_soft_dev_con = 2 Then prog_soft_dev_con = 0
                    End If
                
            'Check for completer status
            ElseIf acc_comp >= 21 And acc_comp <= 25 Or _
                   pl_an_sys_comp = 50 Or _
                   pl_an_sys_comp = 60 Or _
                   auto_tech_comp >= 21 And auto_tech_comp <= 23 Or _
                   cul_art_comp >= 21 And cul_art_comp <= 25 Or _
                   dig_art_des_comp >= 21 And dig_art_des_comp <= 23 Or _
                   ece_comp >= 31 And ece_comp <= 37 Or _
                   envi_nat_res_comp = 40 Or _
                   envi_nat_res_comp = 50 Or _
                   gen_manag_comp >= 21 And gen_manag_comp <= 26 Or _
                   graph_comm_comp >= 21 Or graph_comm_comp <= 23 Or _
                   health_sci_comp >= 21 Or health_sci_comp <= 28 Or _
                   horti_comp = 40 Or _
                   horti_comp = 50 Or _
                   mark_manag_comp >= 21 And mark_manag_comp <= 24 Or _
                   mark_manag_comp = 30 Or _
                   media_tech_comp >= 21 And media_tech_comp <= 23 Or _
                   pltw_biomed_sci_comp >= 21 And pltw_biomed_sci_comp <= 26 Or _
                   pltw_pre_eng_comp >= 22 And pltw_pre_eng_comp <= 26 Or _
                   sports_med_comp >= 21 And sports_med_comp <= 27 Or _
                   fam_con_sci_comp >= 21 And fam_con_sci_comp <= 26 Or _
                   fam_con_sci_comp = 30 Or _
                   prog_soft_dev_comp >= 21 And prog_soft_dev_comp <= 25 Then
                    
                        pc.Activate
                        term_match = Application.Match(main.Cells(i, 14), pc.Range(Cells(4, 77), Cells(30, 77)), 0)
                        
                        If IsError(term_match) Then
                        ElseIf term_match > 0 Then
                        
                            If IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 3)) Then
                            
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 3) = "Y"
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 5) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                            
                            ElseIf Not IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 3)) And IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 9)) Then
                            
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 9) = "Y"
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 11) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                                
                            End If
                        
                        End If
                    
                        
                        'reset completer
                        If acc_comp >= 21 And acc_comp <= 25 Then acc_comp = 0
                        ElseIf pl_an_sys_comp = 50 Or _
                               pl_an_sys_comp = 60 Then pl_an_sys_comp = 0
                        ElseIf auto_tech_comp >= 21 And auto_tech_comp <= 23 Then auto_tech_comp = 0
                        ElseIf cul_art_comp >= 21 And cul_art_comp <= 25 Then cul_art_comp = 0
                        ElseIf dig_art_des_comp >= 21 And dig_art_des_comp <= 23 Then dig_art_des_comp = 0
                        ElseIf ece_comp >= 31 And ece_comp <= 37 Then ece_comp = 0
                        ElseIf envi_nat_res_comp = 40 Or _
                               envi_nat_res_comp = 50 Then envi_nat_res_comp = 0
                        ElseIf gen_manag_comp >= 21 And gen_manag_comp <= 26 Then gen_manag_comp = 0
                        ElseIf graph_comm_comp >= 21 Or graph_comm_comp <= 23 Then graph_comm_comp = 0
                        ElseIf health_sci_comp >= 21 Or health_sci_comp <= 28 Then health_sci_comp = 0
                        ElseIf horti_comp = 40 Or _
                               horti_comp = 50 Then horti_comp = 0
                        ElseIf mark_manag_comp >= 21 And mark_manag_comp <= 24 Or _
                               mark_manag_comp = 30 Then mark_manag_comp = 0
                        ElseIf media_tech_comp >= 21 And media_tech_comp <= 23 Then media_tech_comp = 0
                        ElseIf pltw_biomed_sci_comp >= 21 And pltw_biomed_sci_comp <= 26 Then pltw_biomed_sci_comp = 0
                        ElseIf pltw_pre_eng_comp >= 22 And pltw_pre_eng_comp <= 26 Then pltw_pre_eng_comp = 0
                        ElseIf sports_med_comp >= 21 And sports_med_comp <= 27 Then sports_med_comp = 0
                        ElseIf fam_con_sci_comp >= 21 And fam_con_sci_comp <= 26 Or _
                               fam_con_sci_comp = 30 Then fam_con_sci_comp = 0
                        ElseIf prog_soft_dev_comp >= 21 And prog_soft_dev_comp <= 25 Then prog_soft_dev_comp = 0
                        End If
                        
            End If
                            
                            
         Else
                   
            'Accounting 1
            If main.Cells(i, 7) = pc.Cells(3, 3) Then
                    
                acc_con = acc_con + 1
                more increments
                    
            'Accounting 2
            ElseIf main.Cells(i, 7) = pc.Cells(4, 3) Then
            
                ton more incrementing but had to cut due to length
            
            End If
                
                
            'Check for concentrator status
            If acc_con = 2 Or _
               pl_an_sys_con = 50 Or _
               auto_tech_con = 2 Or _
               cul_art_con = 2 Or _
               dig_art_des_con = 2 Or _
               ece_con = 2 Or _
               envi_nat_res_con = 2 Or _
               gen_manag_con = 2 Or _
               graph_comm_con = 2 Or _
               health_sci_con = 2 Or _
               horti_con = 1 Or _
               mark_manag_con = 2 Or _
               media_tech_con = 2 Or _
               pltw_biomed_sci_con = 2 Or _
               pltw_pre_eng_con = 2 Or _
               pltw_pre_eng_con = 3 Or _
               sports_med_con = 2 Or _
               fam_con_sci_con = 2 Or _
               prog_soft_dev_con = 2 Then

                    pc.Activate
                    term_match = Application.Match(main.Cells(i, 14), pc.Range(Cells(4, 77), Cells(30, 77)), 0)
                    
                    If IsError(term_match) Then
                    ElseIf term_match > 0 Then
                    
                        If IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 2)) Then
                            
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 2) = "Y"
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 6) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                        
                        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 2)) And IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 8)) Then
                            
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 8) = "Y"
                            pso.Cells(DestRow, 12) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                        
                        Else
                        End If
                    
                    End If
                    
                    
                    
                
            'Check for completer status
            ElseIf acc_comp >= 21 And acc_comp <= 25 Or _
                   pl_an_sys_comp = 50 Or _
                   pl_an_sys_comp = 60 Or _
                   auto_tech_comp >= 21 And auto_tech_comp <= 23 Or _
                   cul_art_comp >= 21 And cul_art_comp <= 25 Or _
                   dig_art_des_comp >= 21 And dig_art_des_comp <= 23 Or _
                   ece_comp >= 31 And ece_comp <= 37 Or _
                   envi_nat_res_comp = 40 Or _
                   envi_nat_res_comp = 50 Or _
                   gen_manag_comp >= 21 And gen_manag_comp <= 26 Or _
                   graph_comm_comp >= 21 Or graph_comm_comp <= 23 Or _
                   health_sci_comp >= 21 Or health_sci_comp <= 28 Or _
                   horti_comp = 40 Or _
                   horti_comp = 50 Or _
                   mark_manag_comp >= 21 And mark_manag_comp <= 24 Or _
                   mark_manag_comp = 30 Or _
                   media_tech_comp >= 21 And media_tech_comp <= 23 Or _
                   pltw_biomed_sci_comp >= 21 And pltw_biomed_sci_comp <= 26 Or _
                   pltw_pre_eng_comp >= 22 And pltw_pre_eng_comp <= 26 Or _
                   sports_med_comp >= 21 And sports_med_comp <= 27 Or _
                   fam_con_sci_comp >= 21 And fam_con_sci_comp <= 26 Or _
                   fam_con_sci_comp = 30 Or _
                   prog_soft_dev_comp >= 21 And prog_soft_dev_comp <= 25 Then
                    
                        pc.Activate
                        term_match = Application.Match(main.Cells(i, 14), pc.Range(Cells(4, 77), Cells(30, 77)), 0)
                        
                        If IsError(term_match) Then
                        ElseIf term_match > 0 Then
                        
                            If IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 3)) Then
                            
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 3) = "Y"
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 5) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                            
                            ElseIf Not IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 3)) And IsEmpty(pso.Cells(DestRow, 9)) Then
                            
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 1) = main.Cells(i, 1)
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 9) = "Y"
                                pso.Cells(DestRow, 11) = pc.Cells(term_match, 78)
                                
                            Else
                            End If
                        
                        End If
                    
            End If
            
            'reset all concentrator and completer counts (next line is a new student)
            acc_con = 0
            acc_comp = 0
            pl_an_sys_con = 0
            pl_an_sys_comp = 0
            auto_tech_con = 0
            auto_tech_comp = 0
            cul_art_con = 0
            cul_art_comp = 0
            dig_art_des_con = 0
            dig_art_des_comp = 0
            ece_con = 0
            ece_comp = 0
            envi_nat_res_con = 0
            envi_nat_res_comp = 0
            gen_manag_con = 0
            gen_manag_comp = 0
            graph_comm_con = 0
            graph_comm_comp = 0
            health_sci_con = 0
            health_sci_comp = 0
            horti_con = 0
            horti_comp = 0
            mark_manag_con = 0
            mark_manag_comp = 0
            media_tech_con = 0
            media_tech_comp = 0
            pltw_biomed_sci_con = 0
            pltw_biomed_sci_comp = 0
            pltw_pre_eng_con = 0
            pltw_pre_eng_comp = 0
            sport_med_con = 0
            sport_med_comp = 0
            fam_con_sci_con = 0
            fam_con_sci_comp = 0
            prog_soft_dev_con = 0
            prog_soft_dev_comp = 0
            
            DestRow = pso.Range("A" & main.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        
        End If

    Next i

End Sub

Here is the summary
Public Sub increments()
    
    for i = 2 to lastrow
        
        if stu_id = stu_id + 1 then

            if .....
                increment variables
            end if

            if ..... (check con status)
                
                if .....
                    if .....
                        display results
                    end if
                end if
                
                if .....
                    reset con variables
                end if

            elseif ..... (check comp status)
                
                if .....
                    if .....
                        display results
                    end if
                end if

                if .....
                    reset comp variables
                end if

            end if 'line the error occurs


        else


            if .....
                increment variables
            end if

            if ..... (check con status)
                
                if .....
                    if .....
                        display results
                    end if
                end if

            elseif ..... (check comp status)
                
                if .....
                    if .....
                        display results
                    end if
                end if

            end if

            reset all variables to 0

        end if

    next i

end sub

Thank you in advance.
Sincerely, a forever student.

You are mixing multi-line if statements and single line if statements.

@Warcupine I had a feeling that was the case. I just can't figure out which are considered single by VBA.

First: Use Select case instead of all your if etc...  where you look at the same value  - e.g. main.Cells(i, 7) but most you will never understand your code in one month and somebody else will not understand at all
Name your variables with clear names
And check the conditions to be  separated and if they are really needed this way
It smells with all these or's

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541024/if-statements-in-vba

@BigBen Your link I understand because those are easy to see single line if statements that don't need an end if.  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, but I am still not seeing it.

This is invalid: If acc_comp >= 21 And acc_comp <= 25 Then acc_comp = 0, immediately followed by ElseIf pl_an_sys_comp = 50 Or _. The first is a single-line statement.

I'll have to relook at those parts and rewrite them so that they are valid once I can look at this again.  Thank you for the hints. @BigBen

You have two places where you mix up single line If-statements with normal If-statements.
Bigben found already 1 of the 2 places (see comments), the other is where you have a comment in your code 'reset concentrator
You can see if an If-statement is a Single Line If when you have code after the Then keyword:
If acc_con = 2 Then acc_con = 0

That statement is short for
If acc_con = 2 Then 
    acc_con = 0
End If

As you notice, there is an implicit End If - with other words, you can't have an Else or ElseIf for that If on a new line. You can have an Else (but no ElseIf) on the same line (but you should avoid that).
If acc_con = 2 Then acc_con = 0 Else acc_con = 99

So change your code to
'reset concentrator
If acc_con = 2 Then 
    acc_con = 0
ElseIf pl_an_sys_con = 50 Then 
    pl_an_sys_con = 0
ElseIf auto_tech_con = 2 Then 
    auto_tech_con = 0
ElseIf cul_art_con = 2 Then 
    (...) 

and
'reset completer
If acc_comp >= 21 And acc_comp <= 25 Then
    acc_comp = 0
ElseIf pl_an_sys_comp = 50 Or pl_an_sys_comp = 60 Then
    pl_an_sys_comp = 0
ElseIf auto_tech_comp >= 21 And auto_tech_comp <= 23 Then
    auto_tech_comp = 0
(...)


Thank you. Very clear and concise.  I’ll rework the code later tonight and label the answer. Thanks again.
